# "undefined" for alerting an ajax call response , why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to alert the return value captured by the ajax request. The web method it is refering is returning a boolean value of true or false, and when i am trying to access it outside the ajax method it gives a message "undefined" :?

```
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

       $(document).ready(function () {
           var authInfo;

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "service.asmx/getAuthInfo",
               data: "{}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (msg) {
                   authInfo = msg.d;

               },


           });

           alert(authInfo);          

       });

    </script>
```

why is the alert(authInfo) giving me as "undefined" ?? Please help !

where does this piece of code fit on the above context ?

```
if(auhthInfo){

                        $(".ansitem").editable('FetchUpdate.aspx', {

                    style: 'background-color:inherit;',
                    type: 'textarea', 
                    indicator: '<img src="spinner.gif">',
                    event: 'dblclick',
                    onblur: 'submit', 
                    submitdata: function (value, settings) { 
                        return { orgval: value};
                        },

                   });


                   };
```

Comment: I think you have an error on server side, check the response via firebug on FF or developer tools on chrome, it could be because of invalid json also, anyway you need to check what server outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED TO HANDLE YOUR NEW CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var authInfo;
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "service.asmx/getAuthInfo",
           data: "{}",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (msg) {
               // alert(msg.d); // here it will work as it is only called when it succeeds.
               MyHanlder(msg);
           },
       });
       // alert(authInfo); // here authinfo has no value as the AJAX call may not have returned.
   });

   function MyHandler(msg) {
      if(msg.d){
           $(".ansitem").editable('FetchUpdate.aspx', {
               style: 'background-color:inherit;',
               type: 'textarea', 
               indicator: '<img src="spinner.gif">',
               event: 'dblclick',
               onblur: 'submit', 
               submitdata: function (value, settings) { return { orgval: value}; },
            });
       };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i edited the question , can u check it and tell me where the last piece of code block shud fit ?

Comment: @Shane place it where the `alert(msg.d)` is, replacing `authInfo` with `msg.d`

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz - Kevin B. is right, but I would also suggest writing your second bit of code as a function in and of itself, and passing calling it in the success section of your AJAX call, and passing `msg.d` to it... this keeps the AJAX call clean, and your handler method easy to maintain elsewhere. That answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Your "$.ajax()" call is **asynchronous**, and thus the results are not available until the response is returned from the server.

If you put your "alert()" inside the "success" callback, it should work (if the HTTP transaction works).

Comment: so how do i put conditional logic there ? :/

Comment: You could either put your entire logic inside success block.. or you can call a function passing the variable that you want to use and move your logic to that function

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz yes, like Ajai says you would put all your logic either directly in the "success" handler, or put a call to a function in there and then put the logic in that function. The point is that until the browser calls that "success" handler in response to the request being complete, it will not yet have completed. There's no way to tell the browser to "wait" for an asynchronous request to complete.

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz I've included some sample code in my answer, showing what Pointy is talking about. Bottom line is Pointy's answer is correct and best explained.

Answer (score 1):

It appears:

```
alert(authInfo);
```

Is running immediately when your document is ready.

However, the variable is not being initialized until after the AJAX call completes.

Try moving the alert to:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "service.asmx/getAuthInfo",
   data: "{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (msg) {
       authInfo = msg.d;
       alert(authInfo);
   },
});
```

If you need to do anything more complex with the value, you can try re-factoring the code into another function:

```
function onSuccess(msg)
{
   if(msg.d)
   {
      window.alert('The value is true!');
   }
   else
   {
      window.alert('The value is false!')
   }
}

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "service.asmx/getAuthInfo",
   data: "{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: onSuccess,
});
```

Comment: I needed to get the authInfo to do some condtional logic !

Comment: You'll need to evaluate `authInfo` in your `success:` function, or call another function from there.

Comment: you need to pass in the parameter right ? in the method call u did not put the parameter

Comment: The `success:` key simply takes a reference to a function object.  Whatever ends up calling it will pass in any arguments.

Comment: thanks @Mike , this is what i wanted ! I tried this way too earlier, but i tried passing parameters which was the problem !

Comment: Yup, if you had `success: onSuccess(msg)` then you'd actually be *calling* that function and setting `success:` to whatever that function returned!

Answer (score 1):

The request and the response that you get via ajax calls are `asynchronous`. I think it is not possible to alert the value that you get in response at the end of ready function because you are not assured that you will be getting your response before the function completes execution.

Answer (score 1):

You are alerting the `authInfo` variable before the actual ajax call have returned. If you try this:

```
success:function(msg) {
   authInfo = msg.d;
   alert(authInfo);
}
```

I think you will get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Because the AJAX call is done asynchronously, the alert does not have the value at the time of execution.  If you place the alert inside the success function you should see the appropriate results.  I also noticed you have an extra comma in the $.ajax parameters after the success function parameter.